# How to quantify the effectiveness of a baseball statistics prediction model?

Tags: statistics

I'm working on a model to predict baseball statistics based on the previous season's statistics. I ran the 2010 stats through my model, giving me predicted values for 2011 for a particular statistic. So now I have a vector of predicted values and a vector of the actual values from 2011. What is the best way to (a) quantify the accuracy of the model, and (b) compare its accuracy to other prediction models?

If my predicted values came from a linear regression, I would answer (a) by  calculating $R^2$ (the square root of the correlation between the predicted values and the actual values). But my prediction model is not a linear regression, so I don't know if it's appropriate to use correlation in that way. After all, I would get $R^2 = 1$ if all of my predicted values were exactly twice the actual values (although my model would become perfect if I divided all predicted values by two).

As for (b), I've calculated the sum of squared errors for each model to use for comparison. Is that the best way to compare models?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are modelling the statistics as vectors because you expect some of the 2011 stats to be correlated to each other? If not, you could simplify you life and model each statistic separately, getting some sort of multivariate regression for each.

One problem with a straight prediction vector is that each statistic has a different *range*, so if you do not correct for that you will effectively be giving greater weight to the statistic with the largest range.

You should first center and scale your statistics, then you can characterize predictive accuracy by the distance between the predicted vector and the actual vector. A good metric would be to minimize the average prediction distance under X-fold cross validation ($X$ is typically 5 or 10).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Perhaps I was unclear. The vectors are all the same statistic [Wins Above Replacement (WAR), if you're curious]. So my predicted values vector contains Player 1's predicted WAR for its first entry, Player 2's predicted WAR for its second entry, and so on. My actual values vector contains Player 1's actual WAR for its first entry, Player 2's actual WAR for its second entry, and so forth. I want to know how to calculate the accuracy of the predicted values vector. (Note: I did center and scale the stats that went into the prediction model.)

Comment: @Lawrence303 ah...any reason least squares will not work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "least squares" here. I'm familiar with using least squares to estimate parameters in a regression model. But my prediction model is not a regression, so there are no parameters to estimate. My model has already generated the predicted values, so I want to calculate their accuracy.

Comment: @Lawrence303 sorry, I should clarify. I was referring to using the squared euclidean norm of the difference between your predicted and actual statistics vectors. This would the the metric you could use in, say, a cross-validation scheme to help tune your model's hyperparameters.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Bey.

Comment: @Lawrence303 no prob.